# Update table list in wordpress plugin admin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins, sql-update

I have this script that should update the data when I change its value. But this code is not working. I dont know whats the problem with it.

```
function update_data(){
global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['update'])) 
                {
                        $won = $_POST['won'];
                        $lost = $_POST['lost'];
                        $pct = $_POST['pct'];
                        $streak = $_POST['streak'];

                    $id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT a.team_id, a.team_name, a.program_id ,b.games_won, b.games_lost, b.game_pct, b.winning_streak
                                FROM  program_teams as a
                                INNER JOIN program_team_standings as b
                                ON a.team_id=b.team_id");    
                    foreach ($id as $row) {
                         $id = $row->team_id;
                }
                $we = $wpdb->query("UPDATE program_team_standings
                            SET games_won = '$won',
                                games_lost ='$lost',
                                game_pct = '$pct',
                                winning_streak => '$streak'
                            WHERE team_id => '$id' ");                           
        echo "<script>alert('Team is now updated'); </script>";
}
```

I hope someone can help me.thank you!

Comment: Check the php error log.. and turn on the wp_debug mode in wp-config.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

Check in Your Query.

```
 $we = $wpdb->query("UPDATE program_team_standings
                            SET games_won = '".$won."',
                                games_lost ='".$lost."',
                                game_pct = '".$pct."',
                                winning_streak => '".$streak."'
                            WHERE team_id => '".$id."' ");
```

Comment: please add me in your linkedin.@renielle curioso